# Combine HTML conditional comments to include IE8+ and not IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, comments, conditional-statements

I know that for targeting IE8+ you should use:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher<br />
<![endif]-->
```

For targeting non IE browsers you can use:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is not IE<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

You can also combine conditions like this:

```
[if (IE 6)|(IE 7)]
```

But my problem, now that I want to target IE8+ or non IE browsers, I try to target them like this:

```
<!--[if (!IE)|(gte IE 8)]> -->
This should be non IE or IE8+ browsers
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

This seems to work for non ie browsers but add `-->` to IE.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the types of comments *downlevel revealed*, and *downlevel hidden*, but I'm not sure how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

From: [link](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/detect/detect-ie.html)

> The next example is the opposite: "Only show this content if the
>   browser is NOT Internet Explorer".

```
<![if !IE]>
Place content here to target all users not using Internet Explorer.
<![endif]>
```

Conditional comments are only recognized by Internet Explorer — other browsers treat them as normal comments and ignore them. Note that in the second example above (the one that targets "other" browsers), the content is not actually inside a comment — that's why other browsers display it.

So I think that you can not combine two different types of conditional comments

Comment: Ahh gotcha, it was confusing the hell out of me, so, in conclusion, I have to have three conditional comments? one for less that ie8, one for greater than and another one for non ie browsers?

Comment: "one for non ie browsers?" - No, just serve up the regular css file.

Comment: @NickR I don't understand what you mean, that would make duplicate content in ie.

Comment: Unless special needs I would do so:

1 - normal stylesheet for all browsers
2 - conditional comments for IE version <8
3 - conditional comment for IE8 +

Comment: @Trufa No, So you would have a main stylesheet, and then if things need overriding in a specific version of IE, Say 7 for example - you would use this override to fix CSS bugs. You don't need to duplicate the whole CSS file and serve it to a specific version of IE. Maybe it's worth getting some background on what you're actually trying to achieve with the separate stylesheets - what do you need to override?

Comment: @NickR I have a feeling that what I'm doing is hacky, I have an embedded iframe that can't modify, the iframe only works for ie8+ and will be only only shown if so. So for ie8+ and non IE users, I show them a link that makes scrolls them to the iframe, otherwise, it's a link to a form that works with ie8-

Comment: I end up having to duplicate the conditionals for those which are not IE, and for IE vX and above.   The "well-behaved" content must be duplicated, unfortunately. Since it's only CSS style sheets, it's not too bad, but still ugly!

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me.  I ended up having to include the non-IE-8 css twice:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie8.css"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/non_ie8.css"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/non_ie8.css"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Of course, this causes a performance hit, and makes the code harder to maintain.  It does, however, work (at least on the browsers I've tried).

You might consider a good css library, if you can find one that meets your needs.